# NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver 1

Tags: google-colaboratory

Good afternoon. NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running. - such an inscription appears despite the fact that it is subscribed to colab pro. My settings are correct. Help me, I don't know where to write.

Comment: Unable to connect to accelerator (GPU)
Unable to connect to the accelerator (GPU) due to usage limits in Colab. Read more…
Colab Pro subscribers have access to GPU accelerators and higher usage limits. If you want priority access to GPU accelerators and even higher limits, choose Colab Pro+. - where do i get the limit if i have colab pro

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.